# Boolean in method, triangle sign pops up and dont know how to solve, exam in 30min

Tags: java, performance, methods, boolean

My problem is that a yellow warning sign(?) pops up and my method/main class don't work.

```
package ïnnanprovet;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author robin.dahlkvist
 */
public class Ïnnanprovet {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //* boolean check
        prt("Enter a character: ");
        char character = (in.nextLine()).charAt(0);
        boolean numberOrCharacter = siffra(character);
        if (numberOrCharacter = true) {
            prtln("It's a number");
        }
        if (numberOrCharacter = false) {   //on this row the warning comes up.
            prtln("It's not a number");
        }
    }

    static boolean siffra(char character) {
        boolean numberOrCharacter = false;
        char theNumber = '0';
        char[] number = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',};
        for (int n = 0; n < number.length; n++) {

            if (character == number[n]) {
                numberOrCharacter = true;
            }
        }
        return numberOrCharacter;
    }

    public static void prt(String a) {
        System.out.print(a);
    }

    public static void prtln(String a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, if you haven't learned yet to read error messages, you're not ready to take an exam in 30 minutes. What does `=` mean in Java. Does it mean "is equal to"? or does it mean "takes the value"?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I might solve it with a minimum of build in functions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    prt("Enter a character: ");
    char ch = (in.nextLine()).charAt(0);
    prtln("It's " + (ch<'0'||ch>'9' ? "not " : "")+"a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code please:

```
boolean numberOrCharacter = siffra(character);
 if (numberOrCharacter = true) { //numberOrCharacter is boolean
    // prtln("It's a number");
 }
 if (numberOrCharacter = false) { //numberOrCharacter is boolean  
   // prtln("It's not a number");
 }
```

So why you need redundant `boolean` here? Also `numberOrCharacter = true` is  an assignment not a comparison. It should be `numberOrCharacter == true` your IDE may gives it as a notification.

Just use:

```
boolean numberOrCharacter = siffra(character);
 if (numberOrCharacter) { 
    // prtln("It's a number");
 }
 if (!numberOrCharacter) {   
    //prtln("It's not a number");
 }
```

Comment: BTW `numberOrCharacter = true` is an assignment not a comparison.

Comment: plus the `numberOrCharacter = true` sets numberOrCharacter

Answer (score 0):

You're using **assignment** rather than **comparison**:

```
if (numberOrCharacter = true) //Assigns numberOrCharacter = true
if (numberOrCharacter == true) //Checks if true
```

Just use

```
if (numberOrCharacter)
```